# AVSpeechSynthesizer - How to detect dot for milliseconds pause (iPHONE - iPAD / iOS7 xcode)

Tags: xcode, ios7, point, avspeechsynthesizer

I want to read a very long text:

```
NSString *text =@"Long test with dot. I want speaching pause when read dot. How can I do?";
AVSpeechSynthesizer *synthesizer = [AVSpeechSynthesizer new];
[synthesizer setDelegate:self];
AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [[AVSpeechUtterance alloc] initWithString:text];
        utterance.voice = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:[self.defaults objectForKey:LANGUAGE]];
        utterance.rate = 0.28;
        [synthesizer speakUtterance:utterance];
```

I want synthesizer detect dot and pause for 100 millisecond.

Is it possible? How can I do ??

Comment: A dot? Do you mean period? or do you literally mean the word "dot" in the sentence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I mean a dot (.)

but maybe I found a solution also fot char ',' :

```
NSString *text = @"Line one. LineTwo aftre a pause. Line three, pause here again.";
        text = [text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"."];

        NSArray *a = [text componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
        for(NSString *line in a)
           {
           AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [[AVSpeechUtterance alloc] initWithString:line];
           utterance.voice = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:[self.defaults objectForKey:LINGUA]];
           utterance.rate = 0.28;
           utterance.**postUtteranceDelay** = 0.3;
           [self.synthesizer speakUtterance:utterance];
           }
```